# R5RS - Display number from operation as decimal

Tags: scheme, r5rs

I want to display a number as decimal, however it keeps showing as a fraction

Example

```lisp
(/ 7 9) ; --> displays as 7/9 but should be .77777
```

I've tried the builtin `#d` but it doesn't seem to work on operation results, also `number->real` and other variations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, you can use the [`exact->inexact`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/number-types.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._exact-~3einexact%29%29) procedure:

```
(exact->inexact (/ 7 9))
=> 0.77777778
```

Comment: That worked. I find the syntax a bit long for what seems like a fundamental task. Do you know if there is a way to show all results as decimal?

Comment: No, by default Scheme will try to do exact arithmetic. It's verbose, granted, but `exact->inexact` is the only way to go. Well, unless you switch to using decimals from the beginning: `(/ 7.0 9.0)`